# We have 108 pages of tags with zero questions

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags

It looks like we have a lot of tags with zero questions. I did a quick exploration today and found out that pages [1746-1854](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1746&tab=popular) are filled with zero-question tags.

This means 108 pages times 36 tags on every page (hope I counted right) --> 3888 tags with zero questions.

Are these tags on the road to be burninated? Or should they be?

Note that I'm aware that not all of those tags deserve to be burnitated, but the number is too large, IMO.

Comment: Tags with zero questions are usually automatically deleted by the system after one week, I think. Many of those in your link are actually synonyms, though.

Comment: If they have 0 questions then what's the harm?

Comment: Maybe there is a bug, and the system keep tags because deleted question use them. Because 4k of wrong tag in one week it's a lot ...
The warm @Dharman is that people will use those tags that seems to exist because of typo (ex: "javasript") and bad tags will stay

Comment: I guess the main problem here is that synonyms are displayed visually identical to a normal tag.

Comment: Using SEDE queries, I can only actually find [1 tag with 0 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1572598). Meanwhile, [tag synonyms with 0 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1572567/tag-synonyms-with-0-score) is the majority at 3096 tags. This leaves around 800 tags without questions, including [tag:urmom], [tag:infras], [tag:ki], [tag:just], [tag:javasxript], and [tag:timm] all appearing in the tag list [but not with SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1572607).

Comment: @Pluto NB - SEDE data is updated once a week (though the last update *was* yesterday).

Comment: @Elikill58 There's definitely a bug; a couple weeks ago I escalated to CMs an issue with some tags showing different number of questions (the count at the top) at different refreshes (in both directions); the CMs I think opened an internal ticket but no idea what the status is.

Comment: @Pluto Weird, I [just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/just) had to click on a random one and see zero questions and it's not a synonym.

Answer (score 31):

As pointed out in the [comment from yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416848/we-have-108-pages-of-tags-with-zero-questions#comment901417_416848), many (if not *most*) of those zero-question tags are actually [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/616624).

Such synonyms are important and should *not* be removed. For example, many of those listed begin with a dot – such as [.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.dll); clicking on this "zero questions" tag will actually take you to the page for questions tagged [dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dll), for which there are rather more than zero.

With such synonyms, if anyone tries to add [.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.dll) (*with* the leading dot) to a question, the system will automagically convert that to [dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dll) (*without* the dot) when the question actually gets published.

Comment: You don't even have to click on them. If you just hover the mouse over the tag a popup will open with the tag information for the tag to which the alias points, including the tag excerpt, number of watchers, number of questions with the tag, and a link to view the tag (the URL for that will have the alias-target tag name).